# New idea for my simple calculator without switch-case

Tags: c++, performance

I'm trying to implement the first calculator. My old code (switch-case) :

```
enum arithmetic_type{
    add = 0,
    subtract = 1,
    multiply = 2,
    divide = 3
};

inline void calculate(double &var, double value, arithmetic_type type){

    switch(type)
    {
        case add : var += value;break;
        case subtract : var -= value;break;
        case multiply : var *= value;break;
        case divide : var /= value;break;
    }

}
```

*I saw "pointer to function definition" and then had a new idea : Using separate functions instead. Now my code looks like* :

```
typedef void(*arithmetic_type)(double &var, double value); //template

inline void add(double &var, double value){var+=value;} //components
inline void subtract(double &var, double value){var-=value;}
inline void multiply(double &var, double value){var*=value;}
inline void divide(double &var, double value){var/=value;}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct VAR
{
    double var_value;
    arithmetic_type operator_type;
    inline void calculate(double value){operator_type(var_value, value);}
};
```

I see **it's much simpler than switch-case**. And more importantly, I'm going to add some other operators e.g relational operators... So I think this new solution is clearer and also it's more convenient than the old switch-case solution. :)

But I still doubt about code speed & performance. Does it perform faster?

Comment: ever tried to write a calculator without using mathematical operations? (+, -, *, /) i wish alot of fun :)

Comment: It depends.  The only way to know for sure is to profile it.

Comment: Hard to measure for a single operation. We're talking about nanoseconds, maybe microseconds.

Comment: Of course, if you use function pointers, you can't use inline [or at least, the function you end up calling won't be inlined, unless the code is VERY obvious to the compiler]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - as a general rule you have finite resources. In many cases your most valuable resource is time of programming. ***In such case you should go with easiest/most readable version***. From description of your problem it looks like you have started optimizing prematurely (unless it is toy example in optimization).

That said in some cases you care about performance. Usually then you have existing implementation but the performance does not meet the goal (say - computation takes days instead of hours). I doubt that 'simple calculator' came near close to such problems but lets assume it for the sake of argument. Then there is whole branch of macro-optimalization you can use - i.e. you should think more about big-picture (change of algorithm etc.) rather then small picture (function pointer vs case). First of all you need to find out what is causing slowdown (if something takes 10% of time program is running and you speed it up by 50% the overall improvement will be 5%, on the other hand if you improve the rest of program by 25% the performance will be improved by 22%).

In even more rare cases even after such optimization the performance goal is high enough that your code still don't match it. IT IS USUALLY ONLY WHEN YOUR PROGRAM IS COMPUTE HEAVY AND RUNS FOR MONTHS OR YEARS ON MANY MACHINES - for example protein folding is worth optimizing in such way while most of the programs, even popular ones, is not. Usually at this point you need to know:

- The exact platform you are optimizing for
- Basic computer architecture (pipelining, ILP, cache architecture, cache-coherence protocol etc.)
- The compiler you are using

If you are in this are it is likely that case/switch performs better because it allows better utilize the branch predictions while using function pointer you are only using BTB. On the other hand if your architecture and you are using very simple C compiler the case/switch might overflow the I-cache (so function pointers will perform better).

---

To sum up:

1. Don't optimize
2. Don't optimize yet (for experts only)

While it is true that in some cases you need to optimize usually you are better off starting from macro-optimalization and recognizing what is source of slowdown. If your program is waiting for I/O anyway (case I would suspect with calculator) then noone will ever know if your program replies a ns faster. Similarly if your parser/tokenizer is the bottleneck optimization of execution won't help much.

If macro-optimalizations are not sufficient and 1% improvement of running time can be worth weeks of your work you might want to look at micro-optimalizations knowing both the processor and compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the function pointer version. It more directly encodes what you want: a set of operations, each being a function.

The difference in speed is really negligible, if any. Argument passing shouldn't be any different, since pointers and `int` are the same size on most system, and your enum is most likely stored using the same size as an `int` internally. If anything, dereferencing the pointer and calling these functions might be faster than performing the switch, which most likely boils down to a series of comparisons and conditional jumps.

Of course, one may say that your operations are so simple that storing them in a function is overkill and unnecessarily high abstraction. I would disagree since these functions provide the essential core of your program, and you want them all to be handled as purely and homogeneously as possible. If you ever need to make one of them more complex, it could bloat a `switch` of all functions, but it wouldn't affect this function pointer-based design.

So, in essence, I see only benefits with your new approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. You used "inline", so function code are being copied to where you use it, no gain there.
2. Pointer sure optimizes performance, but it is hardly noticeable here because you use small sized variables (not like a gigantic photo that would use MBs of memory).
3. Code is not that readable, sure you can understand easily this code, but imagine this convention as thousands lines of code.

So my final thoughts would be do not use pointers like this, use it with big memory consuming variables.

Comment: I disagree with your point 3. By splitting the operations into separate functions, the program logic remains small and easily readable, and each function (calculator button) is a separate unit with exactly one responsibility. To me, that feels like cleaner design. Imagine that the functions do indeed grow very large or very many. Which would be easiest to follow? The one where each function is its own entity, or the one where the whole thing is placed right inside the control flow of a switch?

Comment: Point 1 is wrong: variable function pointer calls cannot be inlined reliably. Point 2 is wrong: pointers don’t optimise performance – if anything, they add an extra indirection which reduces speed. Point 3 is arguable but what you are advocating goes against the consensus of code design.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: If data is large then copying would be expensive, if data is small then probably it is in cache anyway so extra indirection now and then won't hurt so badly (but it might be slowdown unless compiler or instruction scheduler is smart).

Comment: @Maciej We’re not talking about large data or copying here, we’re talking about functions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I thought (possibly reading too much from Selim's answer) that the discussion moved to pointers in general.